# how check if a bool exists in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management

I created a bool in memory by using

```
 bool *SomeBool = new bool;
```

how do I then check if it exists or not in memory, because (to my knowledge)

```
if (!SomeBool)
    //Do stuff
```

does not work properly if the bool gets set to false by default.
so how would i check to see if it exists at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in case you want to check the value, you need to dereference the pointer like this: `(*SomeBool)`

```
if(*SomeBool) { // true }
```

or

```
if(!*SomeBool) { // false }
```

same for assigning some value:

```
*SomeBool = true; // value is now true!
```

Answer (score 2):

The `bool` you've created exists in memory the moment you finish calling `new ...` and no exception is thrown.

However, `if(!SomeBool)` checks whether the **address** of your `bool` is 0, which is never true if your memory allocation succeeds. To access the **value** of the `bool` instead, you'd have to dereference the pointer first:

```
if(!(*SomeBool)) //Do stuff
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add one more thing. Even though your question is addressed.

For instance:

```
sizeof(bool) // size = 1 byte
sizeof(bool *) // size = 4 byte or 8 byte - depending on the architecture 32-bit or 64-bit
```

So, basically you are using either 5(4+1) bytes or 9(8+1) bytes roughly. I don't know your actual scenario. However, It should be avoided by rethinking our design and implementation. It would matter more if you are going to program for small devices where resources are scarce.